# Induced representation - Workout for $S_3$

Tags: representation-theory

I want to give an induced representation of $S_3$. Elements of $S_3$ are given by:
$$e,\ c=(123),\ c^2=(132),\ r=(12),\ rc=(23),\ rc^2=(13)$$ with the following relations:
$$r^2=c^3=e,\ rcr^{-1}=c^2$$
But my question is not just a workout of the example, more a question about the theory how to obtain such a represetation:

Suppose $(V,\rho)$ is a representation of a subgroup $H$ of $G$. We want to make a representation (induced) $(Ind_H^G(V),\psi)$. Notice that $Ind_H^G(V)\cong V^m$ and $m$ the index of $H$ in $G$, thus $|G:H|=m$. Here we define:

$$Ind_H^G(V)=\{f:G\rightarrow V: f(hx)=\rho(h)f(x)\ \forall x\in G,h\in H\}$$ 
with action $\psi(g)(f(x))=f(xg)$. If we choose a right coset representive system $(x_{\sigma})$ of the $H\setminus G$, then $f\in Ind_H^G(V)$ is uniquely defined.

**Now my question: is the following conclusion right:**

Suppose we have $g_1\ldots,g_m$ a representive system of $H\setminus G$.
For all $g\in G$ we have:
$$\left(\psi(g)f(g_1),\ldots,\psi(g)f(g_m)\right)=\left(f(g_1g),\ldots,f(g_mg)\right)$$
For each $i$ is $g_ig$ element of an unique right-coset $Hg_j$. Thus: there is a unique $j$ such that $g_j^{-1}g^{-1}g_j=h\in H$, dus $h^{-1}=g_j^{-1}gg_j$. For such a $i$ and $j$ holds: $\psi(g_ig)=\psi(hg_j)=\rho(h)\psi(g_j)$. Thus we can give the action of $\psi(g)$ by:
$$\psi(g):\begin{pmatrix}
\psi_1\\
\vdots\\
\psi_m\end{pmatrix}\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}
\sum_j{\rho^0(g_1^{-1}gg_j)\psi_j}\\
\vdots\\
\sum_j{\rho^0(g_m^{-1}gg_j)\psi_j}\end{pmatrix}$$
Here $\rho^0$ is equal to $\rho$ on $H$ and zero outside of $H$. Remark that in each colom and each row all values except one equal is to zero. Thus the matrix of $\psi(g)$ is given by:
$$\psi(g)=\begin{pmatrix}
\rho^0(g_1^{-1}gg_1) & \rho^0(g_1^{-1}gg_2) & \cdots & \rho^0(g_1^{-1}gg_m)\\
\vdots & \vdots& \cdots & \vdots\\
\rho^0(g_m^{-1}gg_1) & \rho^0(g_m^{-1}gg_2) & \cdots & \rho^0(g_m^{-1}gg_m)
\end{pmatrix}$$

---

Is this the right conclusion of is there something wrong? I don't know because i work with right cosets instead of left cosets. If something is wrong can someone give the right explaination?

The workout:

$$\psi(c)=\begin{pmatrix}
\rho^0(e^{-1}ce) & \rho^0(e^{-1}cr)\\
\rho^0(r^{-1}ce) & \rho^0(r^{-1}cr)
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\omega & 0\\
0 & \omega\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\psi(r)=\begin{pmatrix}
\rho^0(e^{-1}re) & \rho^0(e^{-1}rr)\\
\rho^0(r^{-1}re) & \rho^0(r^{-1}rr)
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

if $\rho(c)=\omega$ and $\omega$ a cubic squareroot of one.

Comment: You seem to understand the process correctly